# Linking weka to matlab

Tags: matlab, weka

I have written this code in Matlab to link weka with matlab so that i can implement Genetic Algorithm

```
enter code here
import java.util.*
import java.util.Enumeration
import java.lang.String
import weka.classifiers.*
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48
import java.io.FileReader               
import weka.core.Instances
import weka.core.Utils
import weka.core.Attribute
import java.lang.System

javaaddpath('C:\Users\sagnik\Documents\MATLAB\GA\weka.jar');

clear all
clc
v1 = java.lang.String('-t');
v2 = java.lang.String('C:\Users\sagnik\Documents\MATLAB\GA\generateTrainDiv.csv');

v3 = java.lang.String('-T');
v4 = java.lang.String('C:\Users\sagnik\Documents\MATLAB\GA\generateTestDiv.csv');

prm = cat(1,v1,v2,v3,v4);
classifier = javaObject('weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron');
weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier,prm);
```

But this is giving error in the last line as:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.Exception:
Weka exception: Can't open file null.
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Evaluation.java:1080)
```

Please somenone help me,how to fix this! How is the filename 'null' here..I have already provided the 2 filenames..